# Thymeleaf error not displayed Spring 4.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm actually following the [Spring validation tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) and I can make it work properly except for one thing.

In fact, tlhe redirections/template return work great if I validate or don't validate the rules.

The thing is that I don't even see the error message in my template.
I don't know what's going wrong, I use the same code than the tutorial but it doesn't display anything (the template is well rendered).

Could you help me ?

The controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/print", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String printPost(@Valid PrinterEntity printerentity, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("printed", printerentity.getName());
    model.addAttribute("printerentity", new PrinterEntity());

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "index";
    }

    return "printer/secretarea";
}
```

The template view (index) :

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/print}" th:object="${printerentity}">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
            </td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">
                Name Error
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="submit">Valider</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

EDIT :

The form page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">

    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:if="${printed != null}" th:text="${printed}"></h1>

<form method="post" th:action="@{/print}" th:object="${printerEntity}">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
            </td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">
                Name Error
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="submit">Valider</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/print", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String printPost(@Valid PrinterEntity printerEntity, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("printed", printerEntity.getName());
    model.addAttribute("printerEntity", new PrinterEntity());

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "index";
    }

    return "printer/nocontent";
}
```

I can see the content of the error in debug mode with break point and explore que bindingResult objects. The error is in, but it seems the problem is now on the template rendering, the errors are not displayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BindingResult` is using the class name of the object in *camelCase* to associate errors to your object.

In your case, field errors are related to `printerEntity` and not `printerentity` (you should be able to see it in debug mode).

If you rename your object to `printerEntity` in your model, it will correctly display validation errors.

**EDIT**

Also you are using a new instance of your object in the model instead of using the instance you created on the index and which is used in your form.

So your controller could look like this :

```
@RequestMapping({"", "/"})
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("printerEntity", new PrinterEntity());
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/print", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String printPost(@Valid PrinterEntity printerEntity, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("printed", printerEntity.getName());
    model.addAttribute("printerEntity", printerEntity);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "index";
    }

    return "printer/secretarea";
}
```

Comment: Does it mean that spring matches on the camelcase class name for my object ?

Comment: I change it, but it doesn't work :-/ . I load the good page, but I cant see the errors :-/

Comment: Okay so, it seems that the problem is on the Thymeleaf syntax (I can see the error message on debug mode with breakpoints :-) ) Can you help me ?

Comment: Did you change the name to `printerEntity` in both parameter method and model attribute ?

Comment: Okay. It's because you are adding a new instance of your object in the model. You should do it like this : `model.addAttribute("printerEntity", printerEntity);`. I edit my response to give you more code.

Comment: In my case it solved exactly same problem: `bindingResulted` contained the error, but the `#fields` did not.

Comment: Thanks, @lgd I was struggling with this for a while until I saw this answer :)